# How to customize react-select singleValue field with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-select

I made a custom select using react-select and styled it with styled-components. I was able to style everything (control, menu, option, placeholder) using the selectors and change things dynamically via props. I should also be able to target the singleValue field according to the docs but it won't work. I want to be able to control the color of the text dynamically. As soon as I select an option, the text changes to black and that's it.  So if I'm in dark mode, I can't see the text. I tried targeting different fields to see if that worked but no.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';

export const CustomSelect = styled(ReactSelect)`
  width: 30rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
 

  & .Select__control {
    height: 6rem;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans';
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;    
    background-color: ${(props) =>
      props.isDark ? 'hsl(209, 23%, 22%)' : 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)'};     
  }

  & .Select__option {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: ${props => props.isDark? 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)': 'hsl(200, 15%, 8%)'};
    &:hover{
      background-color: grey;
    }
  }

  & .Select__menu {
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans';
    background-color: ${(props) =>
      props.isDark ? 'hsl(209, 23%, 22%)' : 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)'};
  }

  & .Select__placeholder {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: ${props => props.isDark? 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)': 'hsl(200, 15%, 8%)'}; 
  }  

  & .Select__inputValue {    
    color: ${props => props.isDark? 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)': 'hsl(200, 15%, 8%)'};
  }

  & .Select__ValueContainer {    
    color: ${props => props.isDark? 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)': 'hsl(200, 15%, 8%)'};  }  
 

  & .Select__singleValue {  
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: ${props => props.isDark? 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)': 'hsl(200, 15%, 8%)'};
  }

  
`;
```

I can use custom styles as shown to target the singleValue that way but then I can't use my props to make it dynamic so I had to choose a text color that would work for both. Definitely not ideal. It seems crazy that everything would work so easily except this one field. Is there something I'm missing here.

```
import { CustomSelect } from './filter-dropdown.styles';

const Filters = ({ isDark, options }) => {


  const customStyles =  {
    singleValue: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      color: 'grey',
    })    
  }
  
  return (
    <CustomSelect
      classNamePrefix={'Select'}
      isDark={isDark}
      options={options}
      placeholder="Filter by region..."     
      styles={customStyles}
    />
  );
};

export default Filters;
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I was wrong on not being able to pass props to the custom styles. I must have missed it in the docs. I still can't style the singleValue using the selector but I can set a conditional in a different prop and set the value of color that way. Hope this saves someone out there some time.

```
import { CustomSelect } from './filter-dropdown.styles';

const Filters = ({ isDark, options }) => {

  const customStyles =  {
    singleValue: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      color: state.selectProps.changeInput,
    })    
  }

  return (
    <CustomSelect
      classNamePrefix={'Select'}
      isDark={isDark}
      options={options}
      placeholder="Filter by region..."    
      changeInput={isDark? 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)' : 'hsl(200, 15%, 8%)'} 
      styles={customStyles}
    />
  );
};

export default Filters;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case to do dynamic styling in styled-components, I would recommend using **Theme Provider** from styled-components library and pass to it your selected theme like that :

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
</ThemeProvider>
```

theme variable could be state in redux or in context, theme object should contain the theme attribs and you can use it like so in react component :

```
const Example = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${({ theme }) => theme.backgroundImage});
`;
```

Comment: Sure - I've used themes before but I still need to be able access the color property in the singleValue selector which I was unable to do without using the custom styles. I don't think themes will help in this scenario.

Comment: StyledComponents provide useTheme hook that gives you access on the selected Theme object from which you can access your preferred color for the singleValue instead of passing down the styles through props, hope it helps :)